# How to define Array name while returning JSON output

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net, json

Hello I am very new in JSON. I have written a method which is returning JSON output like below:

```
[
  {
    "PostId": 0,
    "Title": "BCS",
    "ImageInfo": null,
    "ShortDescription": null,
    "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "PostId": 0,
    "Title": "ABC",
    "ImageInfo": null,
    "ShortDescription": "Corruption",
    "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

My method which is returning output is below:

```
public string GetPost(GetPost userPost)
{

    var objPosts = from p in _dbcontext.Posts
                    where p.CategoryId == userPost.CategoryId orderby p.PostId descending
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = p.Title,
                        ImageInfo = p.ImageInfo,
                        ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,

                    };

    var listEmail = new List<Post>();

    foreach (var item in objPosts)
    {
        var objresult = new Post
        {
           Title = item.Title,
           ImageInfo = item.ImageInfo,
           ShortDescription = item.ShortDescription
        };

        listEmail.Add(objresult);
    }

    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listEmail);
    return output;
}
```

I actually want to add the array name, so that my JSON ouput can be easily read. I want something like below:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "PostId": 0,
      "Title": "BCS",
      "ImageInfo": null,
      "ShortDescription": null,
      "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "PostId": 0,
      "Title": "BCS",
      "ImageInfo": null,
      "ShortDescription": null,
      "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the list into dictionary like this:

```
var dictionaryEmail = new Dictionary<string, List<Post>>();
var listEmail = var listEmail = new List<Post>();;

foreach (var item in objPosts)
{
    var objresult = new Post
    {
       Title = item.Title,
       ImageInfo = item.ImageInfo,
       ShortDescription = item.ShortDescription
    };

    listEmail.Add(objresult);
}

dictionaryEmail.add("Contacts", listEmail);
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionaryEmail);
return output;
```

Comment: I am just about to give my Question's answer but in some different way. I was passing static string with output like:
return "{" + "Contacts" + output + "}".

Comment: Well, from my experience, it's bad practice to change the serialization output like that, because you will meet some method that depend with json serialization function, and you can't do something about it.